# How to return all images of a model in django REST framework

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write an app using REST API for a restaurant. I have a model like below:

```
# models.py
# =========================================================================
class Food(models.Model):
    food_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    f_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/imgFood/')
    DDD_data = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/DDD_Food/')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.price)
```

when a client sends a request for all files, I want to give it a list of all image files of the `Food` class to it using ListAPIView.

How can I figure it out?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more your question? When you say django REST, do you mean django REST framework? If yes, what did you tried so far? Did you write and endpoint with ListAPIView for instance and the corresponding serializer(s)?

Comment: @gpichot : I have edited my question. actually I had no idea about how client can see all images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `ListFoodImagesView` which extends `ListAPIView`, such as:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class ListFoodImagesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FoodImagesSerializer
    queryset = Food.objects.all()
```

and use a `FoodImageSerializer` that just serializes the image url, such as:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class FoodImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('image_url', )

    def get_image_url(self, food):
        return food.DDD_data.url
```